# Japanese/English speech translator

Tags: portable, translation, japanese

During my previous visit to Japan (2013) I twice saw an app that was able to translate from (spoken) Japanese to English and viceversa, with acceptable results and performance.

One man used an app on a tablet (I think Android), another one offered his app on a smartphone to help me talk with the waiter.

I am not sure if it was the same app, and if a iOS version exist (this would be my preferred solution, but I can find a spare Android smartphone if needed) but I would like to know if there is a recommended app to assist travelers communicate in Japanese?

It does not need to be free - I am more than willing to pay for a decent app.

Comment: I think google translate can do this but I am not sure. They have support for this functionality for some languages but I am not sure about Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it out myself: it is [NTT DOCOMO JSpeak](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/info/media_center/pr/2014/1106_00.html).

Available for iOS and Android. Free for five uses then you have to pay for a time-based subscription (1 week, 2 weeks etc.)

Important notice: apparently it requires a SIM, so you cannot use it on a Tablet or from a SIM-less phone (the SIM does not need to be Japanese, though).